How to add a footer in HTLM to Docx conversion
I have this code where I get an element from my HTML and transform it in docx, but how could I add a footer to it? It should have a left text and the page count on the right. Don't if this i made using CSS or it's something i should add to the Head
export const Export2Doc = (element, filename = "") => {
//  _html_ will be replace with custom html
const meta =
    "Mime-Version: 1.0\nContent-Base: " +
    location.href +
    '\nContent-Type: Multipart/related; boundary="NEXT.ITEM-BOUNDARY";type="text/html"\n\n--NEXT.ITEM-BOUNDARY\nContent-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"\nContent-Location: ' +
    location.href +
    "\n\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n_html_</html>"
//  _styles_ will be replaced with custome css
const head =
    '<head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">\n<style>\n_styles_\n</style>\n</head>\n'
// img {width:300px; border-radius: 12px;}
const css =
    "<style>" +
    "table {border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0;}  body {font-family:  Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}" +
    "</style>"

const { images, changedImages } = prepareImageData(element)

const imgMetaData = prepareImageMetaData(images)

const html = document.getElementById(element).innerHTML

const blob = new Blob(["\uFEFF", html], {
    type: "application/msword"
})

const output =
    meta.replace("_html_", head.replace("_styles_", css) + html) +
    imgMetaData

const url =
    "data:application/vnd.ms-word;charset=utf-8," +
    encodeURIComponent(output)

filename = filename ? filename + ".doc" : "document.doc"

const downloadLink = document.createElement("a")

document.body.appendChild(downloadLink)

if (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename)
} else {
    downloadLink.href = url
    downloadLink.download = filename
    downloadLink.click()
}

document.body.removeChild(downloadLink)
restoreImagesDimensions(changedImages, element)

}
